# Is there a way to import meta descritpions into Joomla 3.2

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

we just finished a joomla 3.2.3 build using jreviews. After adding 15,000+ listings the client decided to change all meta descriptions
Is there a way that i can import them through a csv file?

Maybe through a component or plugin?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Yes, you can import it using phpMyAdmin or similar UI for the database access. There's really no special handling of the description field so you can do it directly using sql assuming you have the correct ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try csv import for jreviews. I am not sure if it can change meta descriptions.

Visit http://www.reviewsforjoomla.com/csv-import